# can't create html content in a loop

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom

I am trying to create new article html elements under a section html element in a loop using javascript that reads content from xml but what i get is only the last article of the loop.

```
//variable holds a specific section element
var section = document.getElementById('articles');

//monument variable holds 2 monument elements from xml
for (var i = 0; i < monument.length; i++) {

    //create articles elements
    var article = document.createElement('article');

    //create the title of the article
    article.innerHTML += "<h3>";

    //the title variable holds 2 title elements from xml
    article.innerHTML += title[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    article.innerHTML += "</h3>"

    //append article to section
    section.appendChild(article);

} //end of for
```

Can you figure out why?

Comment: Can you put your all code in jsfiddle?

Comment: i will try or else i will insert all the code here

Comment: i got the message "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assign two elements arrays to your variables for test.

```
var monument = ['1', '2'],
    title = ['1', '2'];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YP7fj/

It works fine.

So, The problem is in your `monument` or `title` variables.

There is no any problem in the code you showed.

Comment: yes, this is what i figured out as well. i am trying to find what is the problem with title and monument variables